# SPARQL query to access inside a JSON-LD array

Tags: sparql, json-ld

Here is my JSON-LD :

```
"locationCreated": {
"@type": "Place",
"@id": "http://test.fr/city/pacific-grove",
"geo": {
      "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
      "@id": "http://test.fr/city/pacific-grove/geo",
      "latitude": "36.6177374",
      "longitude": "-121.9166215"
    },
    "name": "Pacific Grove",
    "alternateName": "Pacific Grove, CA, USA"
  }
```

I want to get the `latitude` & `longitude` value with SPARQL. Actually, when i make my query, I just have access to the URI `"http://test.fr/city/pacific-grove"` of `locationCreated`.

SPARQL Query:

```
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> 
select ?locationCreated 
where { 
?x schema:locationCreated ?locationCreated
} 
LIMIT 100
```

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work given your sample data:

```sql
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> 
select ?locationCreated ?lat ?long 
where { 
  ?x schema:locationCreated ?locationCreated .
  ?locationCreated schema:geo ?geoData .
  ?geoData schema:latitude ?lat .
  ?geoData schema:longitude ?long .
} 
LIMIT 100
```